# Excel column autofill increment by two steps instead of one

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In cell B2, I have the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,0)
```

Now if I autofill to the right in cell C2, the formula becomes

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!B:C,2,0)
```

but I would like it to become

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!C:D,2,0) i.e. C:D instead of B:C (two step increment)
```

and so forth with

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!E:F,2,0)
```

in cell D2 and etcetera up to more or less 3000 columns.

How could this be achieved? A VBA macro would be fine, but I'd prefer not to use a macro if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OFFSET` for this:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2, OFFSET(Sheet1!$A:$B, 0, 2*(Column()-2)), 2, FALSE)
```

This will start with the target range `$A:$B`, then move it down `0` rows and across `2*(Column()-2)` columns.  For B/C/D this will be 0/2/4 columns

Answer (score 2):

Use the non Volatile INDEX()

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$HZZ,1,(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2+1):INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$HZZ,1040000,(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*2+2),2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.